# Required mobile / tablet touch Slider with elastic easing for Ios 4 -5, android and blackberry

Tags: mobile, touch, zepto

Currently we are facing an issue with one project developed with Zepto framework.

There is a need of content slider same as carousel with next previous buttons and touch slide option.

Client refuses to use any jQuery. All plugins we've seen are not providing smooth easing in all the browsers.

Can anyone help on this? Anyone having slider with smoothing effect that can easily implement with Zepto please provide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [S6](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/s6/) or [Swipe](http://swipejs.com/)?

Also, [Orbit](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) from Zurb's Foundation 4 works with Zepto

A bit hard to know how to help without a bit more detail around "*All plugins we've seen*" (so we don't recommend plugins you've already tried) and what you mean by "*all the browsers*" (mobile? mobile and desktop? what versions? what do you have to support?)